# Is it ok to have a large number of directories on a web server?

Tags: php, ftp

i am developing a website where users can upload items,products ..

each items can have up to 6 images .. what I did is i made directories for each members (using their id as folder name).. and then sub directories under their own folder (using item id as the sub folder name) ..

ex. '/uploads/1/items/1/item-pic.jpg' - where 1-member_id, and the other 1-item_id

what i want to know is will it be ok to have many directories in the server, because as you can see, if it have reached thousands of members, it will also have thousands of directories .. will it affect the performance/accuracy??

Comment: Having many many many folders shouldn't be a huge problem, but there are much neater ways of doing this. For example, you could just maintain a database table with the columns user ID, item ID and image location, and then store them all in one place. Edit: as @Barmar said below, you might still want to chunk this folder up a little.

Comment: @MarkOrmesher .. thanks for the reply i will also try to chunk all the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK, although a single directory with thousands of entries can sometimes cause performance problems. What you can do is split them up based ona prefix, such as:

```
/uploads/1/10101
/uploads/1/10203
...
/uploads/2/2000
/uploads/2/20199
...
```

This uses the first character of the user ID for the first level of subdirectory.